# Reference a sheet range dynamically inside formula by using a cell value

Tags: google-sheets, filter, row, multiple-columns, excel-indirect

How can I reference a sheet range by using a cell value?

i.e

This is a working formula

```
=filter(dump!1:1000,dump!G:G = "Active")
```

However, I need to reference the sheet's G:G range dynamically by using a cell value.
Let's assume my cell A1 contains "G:G" as the value inside it.

My formula would be something like

```
=filter(dump!1:1000,"dump!"&A2 = "Active")
```

..but of course it doesn't work because I'm not using the syntax properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use:

```
=FILTER(dump!1:1000, INDIRECT("dump!"&A1) = "Active")
```

but keep in mind that G:G needs to have exactly 1000 rows otherwise you will face ARRAY_ error

Comment: Thank you! INDIRECT() was what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Use [INDIRECT](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093377?hl=en):

```
=filter(dump!1:1000,"dump!"&INDIRECT(A1) = "Active")
```

Comment: Thank you! INDIRECT() was what I was looking for.